# Git log -S or -G requires precise path

Tags: git, logging

i was looking for which commit introduced or deleted a particular string: `'Sample text'` so i used `git log --all -S'Sample text'` (also tried with `-G`) but it didn't show me anything.
After manual investigation i found that a file in `./components/CommonLibs/ComponentA/req/content.txt` which contains that string was deleted.

So after many tries to understand why git log -S was not working i realized that if i give to log a deeper path: `git log --all -S'Sample text' -- ./components/CommonLibs/ComponentA` it shows me the commit which deleted the file but if i don't precise the path enough i got nothing.

Is there a file limitation number on `git log -S/-G` option ? I can't figure out why i need to give to git log a deep enough path.

Comment: You don't have to specify a path. Can you reproduce the issue on a simple and/or public repo and post the exact commands you typed here (what worked, what didn't, ...)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but since i don't really get the problem i have no idea how to reproduce the problem in a public reposity (unless i spend hours and try n public rep ...).
And i cant post my repo because its for my work.
Sorry :(

Comment: It seems this question is incomplete and will not be reshaped so that it could be answered?